What is the difference between : RTMP, HLS, DASH, HTTP, WebRTC, ngx_stream in nginx conf
Studing nginx I cam to the stream directive and rtmp I found many streeming options
There is many things called streaming and I'm new to these concepts

RTMP
HLS
DASH
HTTP(S)
ngx_stream (stream directive)
WebRTC

Once I want to implement one of them with nginx or any client app I don't understand the difference
What make them differnt especially in terms of implementation and usage ?
I read many questions including :

Media streaming basics - HTTP vs RTMP
send nginx rtmp fragments to WebRTC

And many articles including :

https://getstream.io/blog/streaming-protocols/
https://linuxhit.com/rtmp-vs-hls-vs-dash-streaming-protocols/
https://www.linkedin.com/advice/0/how-does-webrtc-compare-other-video-streaming-protocols#:~:text=On%20the%20other%20hand%2C%20if,is%20likely%20the%20best%20choice.

what I found :

none of them tells anything about ngx_stream

lake of representation of emplementation

every protocol, directive may refer to streaming as a different concept, for example :
flask streams responses (any sequenc of data called stream),
but rtmp is built for video
Is the two streaming protocols refer to the same thing among different methods and protocols

NGinX has nearly all of these protocols, and builtin stream directive what is the difference

could the WebRTC protocol be implemented using nginx

Could some of them implemented together



approach in general is for you to get a server running which does one of above protocols then to aid the server put nginx inbetween the internet and your internal server whereby nginx helps out in various ways

yes but there must be some key differences between them, I cant tell for what one could use them or what is implemention considerations, I just found this : https://superuser.com/questions/1135208/can-nginx-serve-ssh-and-https-at-the-same-time-on-the-same-port, from it I could know that ngx_stream could stream many things, but I'm not satisfied of my low knowlage

You should try SRS, which supports all these protocols, see https://ossrs.io
